# Unable to authenticate Windows XP clients agains Snow Leopard Server PDC after 10.6.2 upgrade

Tags: windows-xp, samba, osx-snow-leopard, mac-osx-server

I have setup a Snow Leopard Server 10.6.1 as a PDC without problems to authenticate Windows XP clients. Joining a Windows XP client to the SLS PDC Domain and log in from a Windows XP client to the SLS PDC Domain are working.

After the update to Snow Leopard Server 10.6.2 the authentication is broken.

`opendirectory_smb_pwd_check_ntlmv1 gave -14090 [eDSAuthFailed]`

By changing the Windows XP "Network security: LAN Manager authentication level" policy to `NTVLM2 responses only` the authentication agains a SMB share is possible, but trying to join  SLS PDC Domain is still not possible.

`opendirectory_smb_pwd_check_ntlmv2 gave -14090 [eDSAuthFailed]`

Any ideas? Is anyone else having similar authentication difficulties?

Comment: same same but different: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2228244

Answer (score 1):

After a fresh re-install of the whole system everything works fine again.

I've install the 10.6.2 Combo Update before I made any configurations regarding SMB or creating OD users. Hopefully this will not happen after the next update to 10.6.3!